# Trouble connecting to an RMI server which is behind a router

Tags: java, rmi, router, nat

Let's say the public IP of the router is 92.1.85.179
The local IP of the computer with the server is 192.168.0.2
The router is set to forward 92.1.85.179:5678 to 192.168.0.2:5678

In the server I have:

```
System.setProperty( "java.rmi.server.hostname" , "92.1.85.179" );
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry( 5678 );
registry.rebind( "TheWebServer" , webServerInt );
```

The client has:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry( "92.1.85.179" , 5678 );
server = (WebServerInterface) registry.lookup( "TheWebServer" );
```

When client is on the network local to the server it's ok. When the client is outside the local network it gets java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.0.2;

Obviously the server is giving the client the IP of 192.168.0.2 as it doesn't appear in the code, which I thought `System.setProperty( "java.rmi.server.hostname" , "92.1.85.179" );` was supposed to change.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your remote objects on port 5678 too, and you need to set java.rmi.server.hostname before you export any remote objects.